# Classical correlations in bipartite entangled mixed state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, quantum-states

I have recently asked [somewhat related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429136/classical-and-quantum-correlations-in-bipartite-system) and got very illuminating answer. After some thinking however  I have realized that (at least) one more point is unclear to me:

> How can we check whether given bipartite entangled mixed state has classical correlations  between its subsystems?

This is what I know about the subject so far. Suppose we are given some mixed state:
$$\rho = \sum_{i} p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$$
here $\{p_i \}$ defines probabilistic mixture of pure states $\{|\psi_i\rangle \} $. This state could be one of three:

- **simply separable(product state)**  $ \rho = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$. In this case there are no correlations(either classical or quantum) between subsystems.
- **separable  state**   $$\rho = \sum_k p_k \rho_A ^k \otimes \rho_B ^k \quad \sum_k p_k =1 \quad (1) $$
  Firstly  by definition this state has no quantum correlations between subsystems A and B. Secondly this state [can be obtained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_state) from product state by [LOCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOCC). This means that given state has classical correlations between subsystems.
- **Entangled  state**  In this case given state can't be written in form (1). It will obviously have quantum correlations between subsystems. Yet what can we say about classical correlations between parts A and B? My guess would be to check whether this state can only be constructed out of product state by combination of both nonlocal operators $U_A \otimes U_B$ and [LOCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOCC).  If  LOCC is necessary then our state has classical correlations between subsystems. However this criterion(if correct at all) seems to be almost impossible to apply in real situation. Is there any other way to resolve the question?

Comment: I don't want to mess too much with your formatting, but I would *strongly* discourage you from using MathJax for emphasis. If it's just text that you want to emphasize, it doesn't belong in a MathJax block. Use italics or bold as required, instead.

Comment: As regards the question: what exactly do you mean by "classical correlations"? Do you just mean "a state that's separable but not simply separable"?

Comment: This is an example that I had in mind. Suppose we start from from $\rho = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$. Then we act on it both by LOCC and by nonlocal operators $U_A \otimes U_B$ to obtain entangled state. Would it be meaningless to say that resulted bipartite state has both classical and quantum correlations in it? Can we say that LOCC may(?) be somehow simulated by these nonlocal operators? If the later is the case then this distinction in origins of correlations will indeed be meaningless.

Comment: You haven't said how you want to quantify correlations, so I don't think it's really meaningful to talk about separating classical from quantum correlations. Two examples to keep in mind:

Comment: (1) Alice and Bob have two qubits each. They perform a joint unitary on qubits A1 and B1 and put them on a maximally entangled state, and they use LOCC to put qubits A2 and B2 on a state with maximal classical correlations, $\rho = \frac12 (|00⟩⟨00| + |11⟩⟨11|)$; within each side, qubits 1 and 2 are described by a joint state but they are otherwise kept separate. How should one quantify the correlations in this state?

Comment: (2) Alice and Bob have one qubit each; they use a joint unitary to put them on the maximally entangled state $|\psi⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00⟩ + |11⟩)$, and then each of them applies a local dephasing quantum channel such that $\Lambda (|0⟩⟨0|) = |0⟩⟨0|$, $\Lambda (|1⟩⟨1|) = |1⟩⟨1|$, $\Lambda (|0⟩⟨1|) = \Lambda (|1⟩⟨0|) = 0$, which reduces the global state to the maximally-classically-correlated state $\rho = \frac12(|00⟩⟨00| + |11⟩⟨11|)$. Should the correlations be considered "quantum" in some way? What if the dephasing is only partial (so $\Lambda (|0⟩⟨1|) =r|0⟩⟨1|$, $0<r<1$)?

Comment: this seems like the kind of question that should be answered via a resource theory of entanglement, in which LOCC operations are taken to be the free resources. See for example chapter IV in https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06107. I'm not versed enough in this topic to give a meaningful answer though

Comment: After analyzing above examples I have arrived to the following conclusion. If given bipartite state can't be created *just by* LOCC then this state is said to have quantum correlations(nonseparable - entangled mixed states, entangled pure states).  If given state *can* (doesn't matter if it was actually created in a different way) be created by using *only* LOCC then we say that this state has classical correlations(separable mixed states, direct product pure states). Would that be a valid classification?

Comment: I have found however some articles which(as it seems to me) claim that one can somehow divide  total correlations in a given bipartite state into quantum and classical parts.  This is an example of such article https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2993 . Could you tell me please whether I misunderstand something?

Comment: There was a typo in one of my previous comments. Obviously direct product pure states don't have any classical correlations. They don't have any correlations between the subsystems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take my answer with a pinch of salt - I do not really know if this works (I guess we'll find out with the upvotes/downvotes).

It appears that the quantity $L(\rho) = \inf_{CSS}S(\rho || CSS)$ might be useful, where $CSS$ is the closest separable state and $S$ is the relative entropy. This is numerical, but it is a convex optimization problem so it is possible to do this on standard solvers.

The CSS state you find through such an optimization procedure can be diagonalized and it's diagonal entries should capture all possible the classical correlations. $L(\rho)$ represents the purely quantum correlations.